# texbox calculation not correct

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running this code that should sum the values of two textboxes which it does correctly up to 999 if the number goes into the thousands the result comes back as 2.00 this is my code:

```
Private Sub Txtunitcost_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Me.TxtTotal.Value = Val(Me.TxtQty.Value) * Val(Me.TxtUnitCost.Value)
   TxtTotal.Value = Format(TxtTotal.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))
   TxtUnitCost.Value = Format(TxtUnitCost.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't recognize `-#,#,##0.00"` as a valid currency format mask.

Comment: I have since changed it to "#,##0.00" but still get the same result anything lager than 999.999 returns 2.00

Comment: Remember that text box.value is a string.  Your code is doing an implicit type conversion, so maybe values >999 are formatted with `,` , and that conversion is failing?

Comment: The issue is that you do not have control over the conversion. You format the text boxes and then change the values again without removing the format I guess. This will lead to randdom conversion. I think you have check each single textbox first if a numeric value was entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code a quick fix could be to remove the thousand separator during the calculation like that

```
Private Sub Txtunitcost_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    txtUnitCost = Replace(txtUnitCost, Application.ThousandsSeparator, "")

    Me.txtTotal.Value = Val(Me.txtQty.Value) * Val(Me.txtUnitCost.Value)
    txtTotal.Value = Format(txtTotal.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))
    txtUnitCost.Value = Format(txtUnitCost.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))

End Sub
```

For further expalnation have a look at the output of the following code

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Val("1000,00"), Val("1.000,00")
End Sub
 1000          1
```

The strings represent thousand for me (german version, depending on the thousand separator) but the result of the conversion is different because of the thousand separator.

And the quick fix is

```
    Sub Test()
        Dim s1 As String
        Dim s2 As String

        s1 = "1000,00"
        s2 = "1.000,00"

        Debug.Print Val(s1), Val(s2), Val(Replace(s2, _ 
                                     Application.ThousandsSeparator, ""))

   End Sub

        1000          1             1000
```

Even better would be to use CLng or CDbl instead of [Val](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/val-function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) because

> The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it
>   can't recognize as part of a number.

So the better fix would be

```
Private Sub Txtunitcost_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Me.txtTotal.Value = CDbl(Me.txtQty.Value) * CDbl(Me.txtUnitCost.Value)
    txtTotal.Value = Format(txtTotal.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))
    txtUnitCost.Value = Format(txtUnitCost.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))

End Sub
```

This is also stated in the above documentation

> Note:  The only valid decimal separator recognized by the Val()
>   function is the period (.). If you use a different decimal separator,
>   as some international applications do, use the CDbl function instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Private Sub Txtunitcost_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim TxtQty, TxtUnitCost, TxtTotat as Long

TxtQty = Format(Me.TxtQty.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))
TxtUnitCost = Format(Me.TxtQty.Value, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))
TxtTotat = Format(TxtQty * TxtUnitCost, ("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"))

End Sub
```

Comment: You are aware that your proposal cannot work as you never fill the textbox TxtTotal with anything. You just define a TxtTotal as long, all the otheres are Variant and not long as your line `Dim TxtQty, TxtUnitCost, TxtTotat as Long` might suggest. And you cannot change the type of a control by "re-defining" it like that. You just define a new variable which now "hides" the textbox (sorry, my english is not good enough to explain it better) and you have to refer to the textbox via `Me.TxtTotal`. PS I assume the TxtTotat is a typo.